# tengo este código para realizar una modificación a un ID pero me sale un error de Exception me podrian ayudar

Tags: java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo este código para modificar el id de una tabla pero me sale un error de exception alguien me puede ayudar por favor.

```
public class consultamodificar{

ConexionPG conex=new ConexionPG();
ResultSet rs;
PreparedStatement pstm;
private Integer con=1;
public boolean modificar(){


    try {
        pstm=conex.Conectar().prepareStatement("select id from peaje ORDER BY id asc");
        rs=pstm.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()){
            //pstm.execute("update peaje set id="+con+" where id!="+con);

            rs=pstm.executeQuery("update peaje set id="+con);
            con=con+1;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La consulta fue ejecutada satisfactoriamente");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error no se pudo efectuar la consulta " + e);
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que quiere decir que no te corre?

Comment: No puedes volver a reutilizar el ResultSet. tendrías que declararte otro y otro PreparedStatement, no reutilices variables para esto.

Comment: muchas gracias por su colaboración pero me sale un error de exception al crear las nuevas variables ResultSet y PreparedStatement

Comment: que error te da?

Comment: Cuando te sale un error, tenes que ponerlo en la pregunta. No es posible saber que error te sale solo viendo tu codigo.

Comment: @EduBw ¿¿?? Aunque el código es algo feo, puedes reusar un `PreparedStatement` tantas veces como quieras, mientras la conexión esté abierta. Igual que una variable `ResultSet` (de nuevo, tal como lo usa aquí no tiene mucho sentido, pero si se hace bien no hay problemas con reutilizarla).

Comment: @SJuan76, Dije ResultSet, ya que usa la misma variable para iterar el bucle y  además para cuando está dentro de él. Y además, dije lo del PreparedStatement porque puede dar conflictos.

Comment: Después de hacer las modificaciones que me sugirieron me salio el error JAVA.LANG.NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION y perdón por el código pero soy nuevo en esto por eso recurro a su ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Para realizar actualizaciones(update,delete,create) necesitas usar `pstm.executeUpdate(Consulta)` 
no puedes utilizar `pstm.executeQuery("update peaje set id="+con);`

Prueba a cambiar el `pstm.executeQuery("update peaje set id="+con);`

por `pstm.executeUpdate("update peaje set id="+con);`

Comment: Realmente es muy feo (aunque, a pesar de algún comentario, es completamente legal) reutilizar el `PreparedStatement` para eso. Realmente yo definiría un `Statement`.

Comment: me salio el error JAVA.LANG.NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION al hacer los cambios que me surgeriste